# Actionbar list popup selector ignored

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

On android when I use the actionbar in list mode, the dropDownSelector of the spinner is ignored.

I use a theme that overrides the actionDropDownStyle attribute and sets a custom dropDownSelector, but the default is still shown. The custom background I defined in the same style is applied.

How do I customize the selector of the actionbar spinner?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a platform bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24922

Set the android:listSelector in android:dropDownListViewStyle to customize the (= every) selector.